# Can't install python interpreter to /System/Library/Frameworks/

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install python 3.7 to my computer. I downloaded python and ran the installer. It just put a python folder in my applications folder.

It did not install the interpreter in my system/library/framework/ folder.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is your OS? What installer did you use? What is in the folder created by the installer?

Comment: I am using high sierra. The folder was called python 3.7. IT had a few terminal commands in it.